# How do I target attribute of opacity in jquery?

Tags: jquery, attributes, css-selectors

I know about the attributeContains selector, but how does it apply to style attributes?

I want to find all `<a>` tags that have their opacity set to 0.

I tried this :

```
$("a[style*='opacity: 0']")
```

But it returns nothing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `:visible` selector will not work because it doesn't give consideration to opacity.

To target just those with a `0` opacity, you could use a `.filter()` to check the `.css()` value of the opacity:

```
$("a").filter( function() {
    return $(this).css('opacity') === '0';
});
```

You could create your own selector if you'd like:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    opacity: function(elem, i, attr){
      return( $(elem).css("opacity") === attr[3] + '' );
    }
});

var $invisible = $("a:opacity(0)");
```

or

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    transparent: function(elem, i, attr){
      return( $(elem).css("opacity") === "0" );
    }
});

var $invisible = $("a:transparent");
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking.  "Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout." http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether or not an element is visible, use:

```
$('a:not(:visible)');
```

Comment: Geeze, we are quick to the draw eh ;) Wouldn't want to verse you in a duel.

Answer (score 1):

`$('a:not(:visible)')`

Your code won't work as it only works when the opacity is applied on the element's style attribute - what about CSS styles??? they won't apply. jQuery provides the `:visible` and `:not` selectors, so you can combine them. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/